# Vietcombank Smart OTP app says "Your device does not match security requirements. Please re-activate Smart OTP on other devices"

Tags: applications, google-play-store, keyboard

I am trying to use the app [Vietcombank Smart OTP on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vietcombank.itcenter.vcbsmartoptv10&hl=en&gl=US). This is the Smart OTP app of the Vietnamese leading bank Vietcombank. The app downloads fine, but everytime I start it up I get this error message:

```
ANDROID
Thiết bị của Quý khách không đảm bảo yêu cầu về bảo mật. Vui lòng kích hoạt lại Smart OTP trên thiết bị khác
Your device does not match security requirements. Please re-activate Smart OTP on other devices
```

[image]

This error message can be seen here:
https://smartotp.vietcombank.com.vn/shield/android.html?4

I have tried this with 3 different brand-new phones and I get the same error message.

Some descriptions for Vietnamese readers:

Không sử dụng được app Vietcombank Smart OTP. Mỗi lần mở app lên đều nhận được lỗi như ở trên.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of trying different things, I realized the problem is that I used Swiftkey. Apparently, third-party keyboards will trigger this issue. So you have to disable any third-party keyboards and use Google keyboard or the default keyboard of your smart phone.

Sau nhiều giờ thử nhiều thứ khác nhau, tôi nhận ra vấn đề là tôi đã sử dụng Swiftkey. Có vẻ như bàn phím của bên thứ ba sẽ gây ra vấn đề này. Vì vậy, bạn phải tắt mọi bàn phím của bên thứ ba và sử dụng bàn phím Google hoặc bàn phím mặc định của điện thoại thông minh của bạn.